# Ubuntu wont install or run from live cd or flash drive

Tags: installation

What would happen if trying to install or run Ubuntu on a platform that is not supported? I cannot get Ubuntu to install or even run from a live dic or flash drive. Ive installed Ubuntu onto an SSD in EFI mode and moved over to the system in question but it will not even see it, same as the live cd. I click on the medium in the BIOS to boot from and nothing happens. Secure boot is disabled. Is this because the CPU is not supported? Is this because Ubuntu was installed on another system and no firmware has been loaded for the unsupported platform? Is there a way to modify the kernel with the information needed to boot Ubuntu? I do not need Ubuntu to be fully functional I just need it to boot. This is an Intel preproduction tablet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to boot to the live CD from a USB memory stick then make sure it's formatted to FAT32. NTFS will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to format the disc or usb to defaults within windows, open the iso with an archive manager like winzip, and copy everything across to the usb or disc